# Calculating length of sides of a half parallelogram

Tags: geometry

I'm building a cabinet with 19mm plywood. The left vertical side is angled at 60 degrees. I am trying to find out the correct length I need to cut both the vertical and top boards, marked A and B in the picture. Using a 3D software tool, I have calculated that the inner sides 136(A) and 182(B).

Could someone please advice on what the correct length is for outer sides A and B? All measurements are in mm.

[image]

Comment: The arrow mark "A" seems to span two boards.  Do you want the length of this arrow or the length of the brown board on the left?

Comment: I marked it incorrectly. Apologies. Please see this one:

<https://imgur.com/a/QpJBqUV>

Only need for the brown board.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow everything.  What exactly does the $138$ on the right measure?  Is it the board on the right?  It appears to be the distance between the inner side of the top and the inner side of the bottom, which would make the board on the right $57$ mm and the height of the entire figure $176$ mm.  Similarly, what are the dimensions of the board on the bottom?   Is it $273 \times 19$ or something else?

Comment: I have edited the picture to add a few more measurements. Please see this. <https://imgur.com/a/TZmpDIk>   The total height should be 176, but measuring the board now, it is 175 as there is a 1mm difference in the thickness of the ply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry, I seem unable to draw a reasonable picture).

Drop a perpendicular from the inner upper left corner to the bottom, and call the horizontal leg of the resulting $60^{\circ}$ right triangle $x$; then since $\cos 60^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$, the hypotenuse which is also the length of the brown board, is $2x$. Pythagoras gives $(2x)^2 = x^2+138^2$, so that $x = 46\sqrt{3}\approx 79.67\text{ mm}$. Then $2x  = 92\sqrt{3}\approx 159.34\text{ mm}$.

Answer (score 2):

The long side of board A is $${138\sin{60^\circ}}\approx 159.35 \text{ mm}$$

Taking the width of board A to be $18 (310-273-19)$ mm, the top of board B is $212.33\text{ mm}$ and the bottom is $230.33\text{ mm}.$  If we drop a perpendicular from the inside corner on the top left down to the top of the bottom board, the side base of the triangle is approximately $$159.35\cos{30^\circ}\approx79.67$$ from which you can get the other measurements easily.